# Should I get my master's in Environmental Science or Environmental Engineering given a Computer Science background?

Tags: data-analysis, ocean-models, education

I'm currently a Computer Science undergraduate at Georgia Tech. I have ~3.5 GPA, and I want to become a data scientist for the NOAA or a similar organization concerning the acidification of the oceans. I want to find *solutions* for this problem instead of just finding out more of what's going on. I plan on doing a PhD in Computer Science and Engineering after that with the engineering focus being related to the environment.

Comment: I've worked with lots of NOAA folks over the years. Great bunch of people. But, maybe do some reality checks. Are you sure they work on this and are looking for solutions, not just analysis? Have you talked to them? What else do you want to do? And do you think there's a big difference between environmental sci and environmental engineering? I suggest you take this question to the academic stack exchange. Good luck!